# How to set default calendar ringtone?

Tags: android

How can I set default melody for alarms in calendar events?

I've only found the way of setting default melody for notifications:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                        SetSongDialogActivity.this,
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                        Uri.parse(songUrlStr));
```